# Unable to Access ENV variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to use env variables in my rails app and set those variable values in **ubuntu 14.04**

I tried setting using export command

```
export mongodb_username="abc"
export mongodb_password="cde"
```

and also tried setting them in **/etc/environment** and in **~/.bashsrc**

and **printenv** gives following results

```
   >> printenv mongodb_username
   => abc
   >> printenv mongodb_password
   => cde
```

BUT in **RAILS APP** or **irb** the output is following

```
>> ENV['mongodb_password']
=> nil
>> ENV['mongodb_username']
=> nil
```

I am missing something? Please help!!!

Comment: This should work. Are you starting Rails and irb on the command line from the same shell in which you set those variables?

Comment: nopes. From a new shell

Comment: @KeithBennett it worked in a same shell

Comment: Great, glad to hear it.  I've just posted more detail in an answer.  If you feel this answers your question, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark, but feel free to wait a while to see if someone else offers a better answer.

Comment: You can try gem figaro [https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When setting an environment variable's value using `export`, that value is available only in the shell in which it was set, and its subshells. So you'll need to export those variables in every shell in which you need them.

However, you can automate this, of course.

If you have variables that you need frequently, one approach is to put their assignments in a shell script and then *source* the shell script in any shells you need them in (see http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html for more on this).

If it's ok to have the variables be in effect in *all* your shells, then a simpler way is to export them from your startup script (probably `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked, basically I was trying on the tab opened shell running before these commands execution

Comment: Also, this is a handy guide for using ENV variables in Rails: http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html